# Issue with Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an issue making " toolbar with Title text " not to Collapse while scrolling upwards in CollapsingToolbarLayout.

I have tried a few tweaks but its not working. Maybe there is a problem with my layout.

**Below is what i am trying to achieve.**

[image: Trying to Achieve]

But when i scroll to the top, the **Toolbar** also collapse, and the tabBar also scrolls inside, and become non-visible. below is what i have now.

[image: what i have now]

**This is my Layout Code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:titleEnabled="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.oxymob.oxygen.customviews.MemberView
            android:id="@+id/view_member"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/include_progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="18dp"
        app:stl_dividerColor="@color/transparent"
        app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
        app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/black_20"
        app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="18dp"
        app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
        app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
        app:stl_indicatorThickness="36dp"
        app:stl_underlineColor="@color/transparent"
        app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    cimplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

}
```

Comment: can you try making height of collapsing toolbar "wrap_content" and also add "title_enabled"=true to Coordinator layout

Comment: hi @AnkitMehta i've just tried it, and it is still the same, toolbar collapse. Thanks to help

Answer (score -1):

In your xml your parent must be a coordinator layout and you AppBarLayout needs an specific kind of theme that is

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```

. I strongly recomend you to follow the next tutorial to archieve the behavior you expeted.

https://www.coderefer.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout-android/

Comment: The parent layout is yet a coordinatorLayout. Thanks but i've followed a tutorial yet.